# Corrupted VIM Indentation?

Tags: python, vim

From time to time the identation within my python scripts suddenly become, i suppose you could say corrupted. The identation will suddenly alter, making my programs fail.

If I look at the file using cat I can see the identation is wrong. But within VIM it shows as fine. Here is the outputs and settings,

Any ideas ???

**via a 'cat -e'**

```
              validate_hostname = RegexValidator(regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',message="Enter a valid hostname.")$
           validate_hostname(host_input)$
   except ValidationError, e:$
               print type(e)$
       print str(e[0])$
       error = str(e)$

else:$
       error = "Please complete all fields."       $
   $
   print error$
   return [error,host_input,record_input]$
```

**within in VIM**,

```
                   validate_hostname = RegexValidator(regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',message="Enter a valid hostname.")
                   validate_hostname(host_input)
           except ValidationError, e:
               print type(e)
               print str(e[0])
               error = str(e)
       else:
           error = "Please complete all fields."

       print error
       return [error,host_input,record_input]
```

my **.vimrc** looks like,

```
syntax on
se bg=dark
set tabstop=4      " insert 4 spaces when a tab is pressed
set shiftwidth=4   " change the number of space characters inserted for indentation
set expandtab      " insert spaces whenver a tab key is pressed
```

Comment: Sounds like mixed spaces and tabs to me. Check for that.

Comment: try `:retab` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: and use `:set list` to see unprintable characters like tabs and spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have mixed spaces and tabs. The code looks different in `vim` and in `cat -e` (or simply `less`) because they use different width for the tab, due to your `set tabstop=4`.

If in `vim` it looks fine, then doing `:retab` should fix it: it will replace tab characters with the amount of spaces as you see it. The result will look the same, but all tab characters will be gone.

It's important to have the right `tabstop` value before you do `retab`. For example if you have the opposite problem--code looks correct in `less` but broken in `vim`, and you do `:retab` in that state, that will break the Python script.

Check out this fantastic article about tabs in vim:

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/

In particular, I think you should add these settings to your `.vimrc`:

```
set softtabstop=4
set smarttab
```

Answer (score 0):

Especially in Python, the whitespace is important, and you shouldn't mix tabs and spaces. Even when you've carefully set up your indent settings in Vim (and maybe even include *modelines* in each file to set the indentation), other users editing that file may not take so much care.

Therefore, I've written the [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690), which verifies the indentation, and complains when it's inconsistent. The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.

Comment: The `pep8` utility does that too.